# INTEGRATING Silverlight with PHP

Tags: php, silverlight, iis

I have a PHP website that I want to integrate with silverlight to provided rich experience.  How can i do this?  Is it necessary to host the website on IIS if we want Silverlight integration.  Do you have any ways I might be able to do this?

Comment: Can Silverlight parse XML? I imagine it could

Comment: Sure Silverlight can parse XML.  There's the XmlReader class, and there's Linq to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by integrate you mean get data made available via PHP, then you could use PHP to output XML which could be read by Silverlight. You could alternatively use JSON if Silverlight supports it (or if there is a parser available).

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight works just fine on a PHP website.  Steps:

- Host the Silverlight .xap file on your site
- Use an object tag (or Silverlight.js file) to instantiate Silverlight

Object tag instantiation:

```
<object width="200" height="200"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="YourApp.xap"/>
</object>
```